# Searching for Word Object in Binary Search Tree

Tags: java, binary-search-tree, frequency

The object of this function is to get user input to find a word that has been added to the Binary Search Tree. Then using my search algorithm in  `BST`, if the word is found, then print out the frequency of the word. My approach was to take user input and create a new Word object then use the `tree.search` function is `BST` to find the word, but this is not finding the word. I am not sure if I should even be creating a new Word object from the user input so I think my error lies there.

Here is my Main approach:

```
public static void search( BST tree ){
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Search For: ");
    Word searchWord = new Word(input.next());

    if ( tree.search(searchWord) == null ){
        System.out.println("Value was not found.");
    }else{
        System.out.println(searchWord.getFrequency());
    }
}
```

This is my Word class:

```
public class Word {
    private String word;
    private int frequency;

    public Word( String w, int f ){
        word = w;
        frequency = f;
    }
    public Word( String w ){
        word = w;
    }
    public void increment(){
        frequency++;
    }
    public String getWord(){
        return word;
    }
    public int getFrequency(){
        return frequency;
    }
    public int compareTo(Word w){
        return word.compareTo( w.getWord() );
    }
    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return word +" "+ frequency; 
    }
}
```

Here is my BST search algorithm:

```
public Node search( Word w ){
    if ( root == null ){
        System.out.println("No items to search.");
        return null;
    }else{
        return search(w,root);
    }
}
private Node search( Word w, Node n){
    if ( w == n.getData() ){
        return n;
    }
    if ( w.compareTo( n.getData() ) < 0 ){
        if( n.getLeft() == null){
            System.out.println("Item not found.");
            return null;
        }else{
            return search(w, n.getLeft());
        }
    }else{
        if ( n.getRight() == null ){
            System.out.println("Item not found.");
            return null;
        }else{
            return search(w, n.getRight());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues in your code.

1. This performs a pointer comparison: `if ( w == n.getData() )`. You want to compare the data inside the objects, so instead write `if ( w.equals(n.getData()) )`.
2. But now you still need to override `Word.equals()` so that it returns `true` whenever the two enclosed strings have the same contents. Like this:

   ```
   public boolean equals(Object other) {
       if (!(other instanceof Word))
           return false;
       return word.equals(((Word)other).word);
   }
   ```

Comment: In what class would the code posted in the second issue go? Word or BST class?

Comment: "now you still need to override Word.equals()"